# Copy Elements from xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

*Disclaimer I am new to the world of xml and xslt so apologies if I lack some crucial knowledge here*

I have an xml file which has (for example):

```
<msg number="1234" lang="en">
```

I also have a build xml file that calls an xsl file which has a few namespaces to extract everything outside of the tags from the initial xml file and place it into a seperate file in a seperate directory. However, I also want this xsl file to extract the "number" element - is there a way of achieving this?

Build.xml:

```
<project name="extract-messages" default="extract">

<target name="extract" description="Extracts the necessary messages from ./messages">

    <!-- Clean ./extracts directory for each test -->
    <delete dir="${basedir}/../extracts" failonerror="false" />
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/../extracts" />

    <!-- Extract the necessary messages from ./messages files to this folder -->
    <xslt basedir="${basedir}/../messages" includes="*.xml" destdir="${basedir}/../extracts" extension=".xml" style="${basedir}/../XSLT/extracts.xsl" />

</target>

</project>
```

Here is an extract of the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="XXX"
xmlns:xalan="XXX"
xmlns:redirect="XXX"
extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
exclude-result-prefixes="XXX">
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this file extracts all messages outside any tags in the xml message files

Comment: It sounds like you need to use the `document` function here to read the second XML file. But to provide more details, can you show a small sample of your build XML file, and your current XSL, that demonstrates the actual problem. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC hopefully I've added what you need